# Using Powershell to clean unused subtitles files

Tags: powershell

I need help writing a small script using Powershell to clean my TvShow Folder.
In my TvShow Folder every video file has it's corresponding subtitle file with the same name with only the file name differ.
For Example:
The Good Wife.S07E06.720p.mkv
The Good Wife.S07E06.720p.srt

**The Goal:**
I am deleting only the video files; so i am finding my self with a lot of "unused" subtitles files. The script needs to go through all the ".srt" files in the folder and check if there is a video with the same name - If not, delete the ".srt" file.

Then, i want to run the script in schedule tasks every few hours to clean my media file.

any help would be appreciate :))

Comment: Hi, welcome, see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**script.ps1**

```
$folder = "G:\TvShow"
$srtFiles = Get-ChildItem $folder -Include "*.srt" -Recurse
foreach($f in $srtFiles) {
    if(!(Test-Path "$($f.Directory)\$($f.BaseName).mkv")) {        
        Remove-Item $f.FullName
        Write-Warning "$($f.FullName) removed"
    }
}
```

**Scheduled task**

Program : `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Arguments : `-file "y:\complete_path\to\script.ps1"`

Comment: tnx sodawillow for your help, but unfortunately the script also removes the srt files that do have corresponding video file with their name. I tried it with:  Blindspot.S01E06.1080p.mkv + Blindspot.S01E06.1080p.srt + Blindspot.S01E07.1080p.srt. By the way, i did read the "how to ask"; is there smething wrong with my qustion?

Comment: I have updated my script, sorry for this mistake. The problem with your question is that there is no code at all in it. You should show your effort when asking for help.

Comment: It is working great now! i am just getting started with coding, but you are right, i should have tried to write it by myself before posting :) tnx again!

Comment: Yes, I know that, and I don't encourage questions presented like this. But I couldn't help answering it. It's still -3. Besides, (and I hadn't noticed it until just right now) OP kinda understood the point, it seems.